# Как сделать редирект из post на get с добавлением параметров в url?

Tags: laravel, redirect, маршрутизация, laravel5, route

Есть несколько роутов:

```
Route::get('/{periodtype?}/{dayfrom?}/{dayto?}/{monthfrom?}/{monthto?}/{yearfrom?}/{yearto?}', 'ReportController@showReport')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/writeReport', 'ReportController@writeReport')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/statistic', function () {
    return redirect('/');
})->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/statistic', 'ReportController@statistic')->middleware('auth');
```

Когда перехожу по **Route::get('/')** с пустыми необязательными параметрами, страница отображается без фильтров. Когда на странице выбираю определенные фильтры и жму "Отфильтровать", я перехожу по **Route::post('/statistic')**, данные проверяются на валидность и дальше должен произойти редирект на **Route::get('/')** с заполненными get-параметрами из текущего post-запроса, но почему-то я получаю ошибку **"InvalidArgumentException Route [/] not defined."**. Делаю это так:

```
return redirect()->route('/', ['periodtype' => 1, 'dayfrom' => 1, 'dayto' => 1, 'monthfrom' => 1, 'monthto' => 1, 'yearfrom' => 1, 'yearto' => 1]);
```

Редирект мне нужен, чтобы по-прежнему оставаться на той же странице, кроме того это избавляет меня от дублирования кода в двух методах контроллера. **В чем я ошибся?** Может лучше сделать не **Route::post('/statistic')**, а **Route::get('/statistic')**?

*P.S. И вообще по этому вопросу интересует более опытное мнение - **как бы это сдалали вы**?*

Comment: `redirect()->route('/'...` - вместо `/` надо указать имя маршрута. А почему Вы не хотите валидировать данные в том же роуте (той же функции), если сёравно же используете get запрос?

Comment: @entithat , вы имеете в виду сразу использовать Route::get('/'), а не Route::get/post('/statistic')? Чтобы обойтись без редиректов?

Comment: Ну как хотите, просто не вижу потребности.

Comment: Уже переделал, один метод в контроллере исчез, а в основном get('/') добавилась всего одна строка при сохранении валидации и прочего. Так действительно удобнее. Не знаю почему сразу так не сделал. Спасибо )

Comment: Да не за что:))